# JavaFX CheckBoxTableCell CSS-Styling

Tags: css, checkbox, javafx, styling

How can I style the Checkbox inside of the CheckBoxTableCell without using the styling for the checkbox (.check-box) itself. (I want the checkboxes in the table to look different from the other checkboxes I used in the program).

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried `.table-cell .check-box { .. } `?

Comment: Well... that was quite obvious. I have no idea how I could overlook that. Thank you!